# Making a counter that increases if value in previous column is different?

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I am making a counter column that increases only when the values at (i-1) is different than that of i.

Below is a sample data:

```
user_id sc_id
1         100
1         100
1         101
1         100
2         100
2         105
3         105
3         105
```

Below is my code:

```
df['subcat_counter'] = 1

for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df.sc_id[i-1]==df.sc_id[i] and df['user_id'][i-1]==df['user_id'][i]:
        df.at[i,'subcat_counter']=df.subcat_counter[i-1]
    else:
        df.at[i,'subcat_counter']=df.subcat_counter[i-1]+1
```

Below is the required output:

```
user_id sc_id   subcat_counter
1         100    1
1         100    1
1         101    2
1 .       100    3
2         100    4
2         105    5
3         105    6
3         105    6
```

Error :

> KeyError: 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
df1 = df[['user_id','sc_id']].ne(df[['user_id','sc_id']].shift()).cumsum().add_prefix('g_')

df['subcat_counter'] = df.join(df1).groupby(['g_user_id','g_sc_id'], sort=False).ngroup() + 1
print (df)
   user_id  sc_id  subcat_counter
0        1    100               1
1        1    100               1
2        1    101               2
3        1    100               3
4        2    100               4
5        2    105               5
6        3    105               6
7        3    105               6
```

Another solution:

```
s = df['user_id'].astype(str) + '_' + df['sc_id'].astype(str) 
df['subcat_counter'] = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
print (df)

   user_id  sc_id  subcat_counter
0        1    100               1
1        1    100               1
2        1    101               2
3        1    100               3
4        2    100               4
5        2    105               5
6        3    105               6
7        3    105               6
```

Comment: this doesnt work, as it gives the same counter when a user comes back to the same sc_id....so if a user if on sc_id 100 (counter should be 1), then user goes to sc_id 101 (counter should be 2), then if user comes back to sc_id 100 (counter should be 3)

Comment: @NitinKansal - Can you change data? Because with your sample data it working nice.

Comment: what can be changed if we want to reset the counter to 1, if user id changes?

Comment: @NitinKansal - I think yes, change `.ngroup() + 1` to `.cumcount() + 1`

Answer (score 1):

if your concern is only the previous row, you can use `.shift()` to get its values, and then do comparisons accordingly. Here we check if `user_id` and `sc_id` match the previous row, and negate it to find the points where we want our value to change. We then convert it to `int` to get True as 1 and False as 0 (this isn't strictly necessary but helps to explain what's happening) and then do a cumulative sum.

```
prev_row = df.shift(1)

df['subcat_counter'] = (
    ~(df['user_id'].eq(prev_row['user_id']) & df['sc_id'].eq(prev_row['sc_id']))
).astype(int).cumsum()
```